# BASH script getting syntax error

Tags: bash, unix

Below is the bash script

the value of b returned by the script is 0 or 1.

```
 b=`tail -l /apps_data_01/mc_migs/inbound/logs/fp.syslog | awk c=$7} {print $c}


if ((!"$b" eq "0"));then

fi
if (($b==0));then

fi
```

Error:

> ((: ! eq 0: syntax error in expression (error token is "0")
>
> ((: ==0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "==0")

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks will try that now

Comment: Please use shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax is the following:

```
b=0
if [[ ! "$b" == "0" ]];then
echo "Not EQ"
fi
if [[ $b == 0 ]];then
echo "EQ"
fi
```

Please note [[ and spaces.

Using the `[[ ... ]]` test construct, rather than `[ ... ]` can prevent many logic errors in scripts. For example, the `&&, ||, <, and >` operators work within a `[[ ]]` test, despite giving an error within a `[ ]` construct. its a good practice to use them

Comment: Are nested braces required?

Comment: `[ ]` is the original `test` command, which is portable to all POSIX shells, but has nasty syntactic oddities. `[[ ]]` is a bash extension, with much cleaner syntax and some additional capabilities (like regular expression matching with `=~`). `(( ))` is another bash extension that does arithmetic only, not string comparisons (but can do more math, like `if (( x*2 >= y+5 )); then`...).

Answer (score -1):

bash uses [] to enclose the condition for an if statement. Also you need spaces before and after the `==` operator. See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html for more details about if syntax in bash scripts.

Note that you can use an else to avoid duplicating the comparison.

Comment: `(( ))` is appropriate for strictly numeric comparisons, but in this case it's acting like `$b` is blank, making for invalid numeric expressions. If some "numbers" might not actually be numbers (and you don't need greater/less comparisons, just equal/not equal), `[[ ]]` or `[ ]` is safer.

Comment: `[` does not "enclose" the condition for an `if` statement. `if` simply takes any list of commands as the condition, and `[` is just one command (an unfortunate alias of `test`) that is commonly used.